# Cannot disable Wake-On-Lan

Tags: network-adapter, wake-on-lan

My WinXP PC currently has a *CNet PRO200WL PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter* that I use for all my internet/networking needs. However, for some reason, I cannot disable the Wake-On-Lan feature of this card. This means my computer **cannot turn off** without physically unplugging the cable.

To be clear, I know how to turn off the feature in the network card settings. I've tried many times, and the next time I shutdown the computer it simply starts back up automatically and the box is checked again when I open the dialog.

Windows says the driver is *dm9pci5.sys* and from what I can find I am using the latest version (1.23.01).

Comment: WOL only works when something is sending your network adapter the 'magic packet' to wake it up.  It doesn't just wake up the computer due to 'any old' network traffic.  When you say "computer cannot turn off without physically unplugging the cable" do you mean the network cable or the power cable?

Comment: The network cable, sorry. As far as I know a magic packet isn't being sent, but I am on a company network and even though it's unlikely maybe it's still possible it's getting one? The dialog box is still impossible to uncheck regardless